# parsing resume using POI in java

Tags: java, regex, struts2

I want to parse my resume using Apache poi API. i want to extract details from resume such as **name of the candidate, Address, Contact number, mail Id, Education details, experience details etc.**. I can able to get only mobile number and address using regex. I don't know how to get above details. And i am also paste my code below. How to get Education Details, experience etc.?

```
public String regex1() throws Exception
{
    destPath = "E:/New folder";

    System.out.println("Src File name: " + uploadDoc);
    System.out.println("Dst File name: " + uploadDocFileName);

    File destFile  = new File(destPath, uploadDocFileName);
    FileUtils.copyFile(uploadDoc, destFile);
    file = new File(destFile.getAbsolutePath());
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
    XWPFDocument document=new XWPFDocument(fis);
    xwpfextractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(document);
    fileData1 = xwpfextractor.getText();
    //System.out.println(fileData1);
    String pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)"; ////REGEX for getting address

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d\\d\\d([,\\s])?\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d"); //REGEX for getting mobile number

    Matcher found = p.matcher(fileData1);

    if (found.find( )) {
        System.out.print("Start index: " + found.start());
        System.out.print(" End index: " + found.end() + " ");
        mobile=found.group();
        System.out.println(mobile);

     } else {
        System.out.println("NO MATCH");
     }

    Pattern address=Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m=address.matcher(fileData1);
    if(m.find())
    {
        fullAddress = m.group(0);
        System.out.println(fullAddress);
    }

    Pattern email=Pattern.compile("\bWord\b");
    Matcher mail=email.matcher(fileData1);
    if(mail.find())
    {
        emailAdd = mail.group(0);
        System.out.println(emailAdd);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("NO MATCH");
     }


    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer("sdgsg sgsdgdsg  Worked at ", "\n");
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()) { 
        String key = st.nextToken(); 
        //String val = st.nextToken(); 
        System.out.println(key + "\t" ); 
        } 

    return "success";
}
```

Here This is my input file.

Comment: Show us sample input and output. Also, show us only the part of code where you are using regex.

Comment: All you are exaplaining is `I can't`. Give us a hand here to help you. Explain, what is the inputs, what you want as output and paste the exceptions you are facing etc ... otherwise, no one going to write code for you. I'm sure.

Comment: My input is sample resume document. i got output as Mobile:9840218630
E-mail: lpriya30@gmail.com. I want to get education details, experience details seperately.

Comment: Yes.. What is the position of each detail like name, id, age etc.. Show us the input..

Comment: My input is a word file. The position varies depends on person's resume.

Comment: What is the regex for getting email ID? By using above regex it varies other person resume's.

Comment: @Sridevi - With so little detail, we cannot even suggest anything..

Comment: Consider my input is "EDUCATION                

 2009-2011                                        Masters in Hospital Administration 
                                                                      Padmashree College of Hospital Administration, Bangalore.India
". If the string "EDUCATION" is match in 20th line, then it display the output of next 2 lines from the matched string that is i want output of 23 and 24th line.

Comment: @Sridevi Upload input file